# Ionic 7/Angular FormControl Validation Not Working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new using Ionic Framework and I have problems with the validator of my form controls. The problem is that the form is shown as valid even though there is an entry of less than 8 characters and the control has a condition of at least 8 characters in one of the controls. Below is the code because I don't know what the error is:

**HtmlComponent.component.html:**

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <h3 class="tittle">Phone Number</h3>
  <form [formGroup]="phoneForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input
      label="Cellphone"
      type="number"
      formControlName="phoneNum"
      labelPlacement="floating"
      placeholder="type cellphone">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <div class="ion-text-center margin-top">
    <ion-button type="submit" *ngIf="phoneForm.valid" fill="outline">Enviar SMS</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

**TSComponent.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-method',
  templateUrl: './phone-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-method.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneMethodComponent  implements OnInit {
//---
  phoneForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    if (this.phoneForm.valid) {
      console.log("Send");
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```